# Point de vue narratif VS Statut du narrateur

Tags: littérature, narration

J'ai été intéressé par [cet article Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_de_vue_narratif) qui insiste sur la non-corrélation entre point de vue narratif et statut du narrateur.

J'ai deux questions :

1. Si le statut interne n'implique pas l'usage de la première personne, comment le caractériser avec certitude ? Je ne suis pas sûr de comprendre le paragraphe relatif à Maupassant.
2. J'ai essayé de dresser ci-après un tableau caractérisant les combinaisons possibles point de vue narratif/statut. Pouvez-vous m'indiquer ce qui n'est pas correct le cas échéant ? En particulier, si la dernière combinaison n'est pas impossible, je serais intéressé par une explication.

   - **Point de vue omniscient, statut externe** : le narrateur est extérieur à l'histoire et connaît le futur des personnages. La troisième personne est utilisée.
   - **Point de vue omniscient, statut interne** : le narrateur est personnage de l'histoire, mais connait les événements entre le temps de l'histoire et celui de la narration. La première personne est utilisée usuellement.
   - **Point de vue interne, statut externe** : le narrateur est extérieur à l'histoire mais ne rapporte que ce que sent et connaît le personnage principal. La troisième personne est utilisée.
   - **Point de vue interne, statut interne** : le narrateur est personnage de l'histoire et ne rapporte que ce qu'il connaît au moment de l'histoire.
   - **Point de vue externe, statut externe** : le narrateur n'est pas un personnage de l'histoire et ne connaît pas les sentiments des personnages (pas même le principal). Il raconte l'histoire à la troisième personne.
   - **Point de vue externe, statut interne** : combinaison impossible ?

Comment: Pour corser le tout, la *véracité* du narrateur est un élément légèrement différent de son niveau de connaissance de l'histoire ou des personnages. Le narrateur peut parfois ne pas tout dire, mentir, avoir un parti-pris, etc. C'est si difficile d'établir des typologies... ^^ Mais malgré l'intérêt évident de la question, est-ce en réalité un point de langue française ?

Comment: Peut-être pas. Mais j'ai pensé que ce serait le meilleur endroit pour poser la question, des esprits affûtés y ayant leurs habitudes.

Comment: Ce n'est pas absurde non plus, c'est bien la raison pour laquelle je me suis limité à une remarque sans proposer la fermeture de la question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Au sujet de l’exemple de Maupassant, l'[article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_de_vue_narratif#Statut_interne), faisant l'objet d'un avertissement et basé sur une seule source, énonce :

> Le statut interne est caractérisé par l'emploi de la première
>   personne, il implique un personnage narrateur interne à l'histoire. On
>   l'appelle narrateur-personnage.
>
> Le fait que le narrateur interne soit un personnage du récit
>   n'implique pas forcément que la narration se fasse à la première
>   personne (exemple : dans [*Pierre et Jean*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_et_Jean) de [*Maupassant*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guy_de_Maupassant), la narration
>   décrit la vision que Pierre a des hommes et des femmes sur la plage de
>   Trouville ; le point de vue est celui de Pierre, personnage, donc
>   interne, mais tout est narré à la troisième personne). Par conséquent,
>   lorsque le narrateur est extérieur à l'histoire mais qu'il adopte un
>   point de vue interne, c'est comme s'il « entrait » dans la tête du
>   personnage.
>
> [ *Wikipédia* « point de vue narratif » @ statut interne (du narrateur)]

On peut retrouver le passage de l’œuvre auquel on semble faire référence :

> Mais tout à coup, comme s'il s'éveillait, il les aperçut
>   distinctement; et une haine surgit en lui contre eux, car ils
>   semblaient heureux et contents.
>
> Il allait maintenant frôlant les groupes, tournant autour, saisi par
>   des pensées nouvelles. Toutes ces toilettes multicolores qui
>   couvraient le sable comme un bouquet, ces étoffes jolies, ces
>   ombrelles voyantes, la grâce factice des tailles emprisonnées, toutes
>   ces inventions ingénieuses de la mode depuis la chaussure mignonne
>   jusqu'au chapeau extravagant, la séduction du geste, de la voix et du
>   sourire, la coquetterie enfin étalée sur cette plage lui
>   apparaissaient soudain comme une immense floraison de la perversité
>   féminine. Toutes ces femmes parées voulaient plaire, séduire, et
>   tenter quelqu'un. Elles s'étaient faites belles pour les hommes, pour
>   tous les hommes, excepté pour l'époux qu'elles n'avaient plus besoin
>   de conquérir. Elles s'étaient faites belles pour l'amant d'aujourd'hui
>   et l'amant de demain, pour l'inconnu rencontré, remarqué, attendu
>   peut-être.
>
> Et ces hommes, assis près d'elles, les yeux dans les yeux, parlant la
>   bouche près de la bouche, les appelaient et les désiraient, les
>   chassaient comme un gibier souple et fuyant, bien qu'il semblât si
>   proche et si facile. Cette vaste plage n'était donc qu'une halle
>   d'amour où les unes se vendaient, les autres se donnaient, celles-ci
>   marchandaient leurs caresses et celles-là se promettaient seulement.
>   Toutes ces femmes ne pensaient qu'à la même chose, offrir et faire
>   désirer leur chair déjà donnée, déjà vendue, déjà promise à d'autres
>   hommes. Et il songea que sur la terre entière c'était toujours la même
>   chose. Sa mère avait fait comme les autres, voilà tout! Comme les
>   autres?—non! Il existait des exceptions, et beaucoup, beaucoup! Celles
>   qu'il voyait autour de lui, des riches, des folles, des chercheuses
>   d'amour, appartenaient en somme à la galanterie élégante et mondaine
>   ou même à la galanterie tarifée, car on ne rencontrait pas sur les
>   plages piétinées par la légion des désoeuvrées, le peuple des honnêtes
>   femmes enfermées dans la maison close.
>
> [ [*Pierre et Jean*](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/11131), Guy de Maupassant, 1887  ]

Et essayer de le comparer à un autre passage de la même œuvre :

> Roland s'écria:
>
> —Tenez, voici la Normandie qui se présente à l'entrée. Est-elle
>   grande, hein?
>
> Puis il expliqua la côte en face, là-bas, là-bas, de l'autre côté de
>   l'embouchure de la Seine—vingt kilomètres, cette embouchure—disait-il.
>   Il montra Villerville, Trouville, Houlgate, Luc, Arromanches, la
>   rivière de Caen, et les roches du Calvados qui rendent la navigation
>   dangereuse jusqu'à Cherbourg. Puis il traita la question des bancs de
>   sable de la Seine, qui se déplacent à chaque marée et mettent en
>   défaut les pilotes de Quilleboeuf eux-mêmes, s'ils ne font pas tous
>   les jours le parcours du chenal. Il fit remarquer comment le Havre
>   séparait la basse de la haute Normandie. En basse Normandie, la côte
>   plate descendait en pâturages, en prairies et en champs jusqu'à la
>   mer. Le rivage de la haute Normandie, au contraire, était droit, une
>   grande falaise, découpée, dentelée, superbe, faisant jusqu'à Dunkerque
>   une immense muraille blanche dont toutes les échancrures cachaient un
>   village ou un port: Etretat, Fécamp, Saint-Valery, Le Tréport, Dieppe,
>   etc.
>
> Les deux femmes ne l'écoutaient point, engourdies par le bien-être,
>   émues par la vue de cet Océan couvert de navires qui couraient comme
>   des bêtes autour de leur tanière; et elles se taisaient, un peu
>   écrasées par ce vaste horizon d'air et d'eau, rendues silencieuses par
>   ce coucher de soleil apaisant et magnifique. Seul, Roland parlait sans
>   fin; il était de ceux que rien ne trouble. Les femmes, plus nerveuses,
>   sentent parfois, sans comprendre pourquoi, que le bruit d'une voix
>   inutile est irritant comme une grossièreté.
>
> [ [*Pierre et Jean*](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/11131), Guy de Maupassant, 1887 ]

Dans le premier extrait, on remarque que même si on utilise la troisième personne (et peu d'ailleurs après la première phrase avec notre personnage directement), on explore le processus mental, on assiste à certains des constats que ce personnage fait; on découvre avec lui son raisonnement au fur et à mesure et il n'y a donc aucune prescience du narrateur et c'est là ce qu'on entend par « entrer » dans la tête du personnage dans le contexte du *statut interne* du narrateur ici; le point de vue est aussi assurément interne. Dans le deuxième extrait on note l'emploi fréquent du passé simple; on relate ce que le personnage raconte, le statut est externe; incidemment, les deux dernières phrases de l'extrait vont dans le sens de l'omniscience d'un narrateur qui qualifie son personnage et connaît les raisons de la réaction des interlocutrices.

Comment: J'ai l'impression que tu cherches à justifier la différence entre point de vue interne et point de vue omniscient. Bien que cette analyse soit intéressante, c'est plutôt la nature du "statut du narrateur" qui est obscure pour moi.

Comment: @SamuelTb La réponse a été modifiée et tiendrait toujours sans le deuxième extrait et sa partie de la réponse, présentés pour fins de comparaison. L'hyper-catégorisation présentée dans l'article est peu convaincante à mon avis. Merci.

Comment: Cela me convent. Pour conclure sur ma question, dirais-tu que la statut interne implique un point de vue interne ?

Comment: @SamuelTb Je réponds à la question en me demandant si le statut interne autorise le point de vue externe - plus particulièrement ici comment entrer ds la tête du personnage serait-il compatible avec l'idée de ne pas connaître ses pensées et de prétendre à l'objectivité; ce n'est pas ce que je vois au 1er extrait. Cependant comme on l'a discuté plus haut, faire cadrer avec les types s'avère difficile, et l'analyse du discours n'est pas science exacte. Parfois on a un récit et dans un passage le narrateur se glisse dans la peau du personnage - même là il y a des nuances ds le degré. R: ici oui.